# Why can't I recover from a transaction Rollback?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and hitting a situation where I can't recover from a rolled back transaction.

I need to loop through a list, and for each item, add some entries to two tables. My code is roughly this:

```
Dim db = New Data.Context

Try
    For Each item in list
        Using tx = db.Database.BeginTransaction
            'add objects to table 1

            'add objects to table 2

            db.SaveChanges()
            tx.Commit() 
        End Using
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    'record the error
End Try
```

I would expect that it would loop through the whole list, and add entries whenever `SaveChanges` succeeds, and log them when it fails.

But whenever the `SaveChanges` call fails, the transaction rolls back and I move to the next item in the list, and then `SaveChanges` fails for **that one too**, with the same error. It's as if the context still has the new objects in it and tries to re-save them the next time through the loop. So, during the rollback process, how can I tell the context to forget about those objects so I can continue to loop?

Comment: So you get an exception and the code then continues inside your for/next loop?

Comment: @DavidG: yes, exactly. But I'm not attached to that design, if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveChanges` synchronizes your in-memory objects with the database. You have added objects to the in-memory model. They never go away until you delete them.

Adding an object does *not* queue an insert. It simply adds an object. Until it has been inserted `SaveChanges` will try to bring the database to the latest state.

EF is not a CRUD helper that you can queue writes to. It tries to conceptually mirror the database in-memory. `SaveChanges` simply executed the necessary DML for that.

Use one context per row.

Comment: This was exactly the problem and your solution solved it. Thanks also for the conceptual explanation of what I was doing wrong.